# How can Contract get NFT's metadata?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

I have two Token Contracts ("AA" = ERC721, "BB" = ERC20).

I will make "Swap Contract" that can give "BB" differently according to the "AA"'s metadata. (e.g. "level").

How do I make the "Swap Contract" for this function to work?

Any example plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting the metadata outside the blockchain you can't do that.
You need to use an oracle. [Read more.](https://blog.chain.link/fetch-ipfs-api-data-token-distribution/)